# Object can't be pushed into an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I have a react calendar program where I have information for every day in an array in my useEffect hook. The property event should contain an object which is being read from firebase. For some reason this is not happening, when I log my object the object is being properly returned but for some reason, it doesn't get pushed into the array.

The full code can be seen here https://codesandbox.io/p/github/MRSinal/react-calendar-ia/draft/relaxed-bhabha?file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FAddingNewChild.jsx&workspace=%257B%2522activeFileId%2522%253A%2522cl9fzbt88000elpix22fhhwsu%2522%252C%2522openFiles%2522%253A%255B%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%255D%252C%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522gitSidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522COMMIT%2522%252C%2522sidekickItems%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522key%2522%253A%2522cl9fzol7o000x376r9sff9jtm%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PROJECT_SETUP%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PREVIEW%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522cl9fzcla7000l376quyhar8kc%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252Fmain%2522%257D%255D%257D

[days array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gf6oD.png)
[The event for that day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6UxS.png)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: seems the sandbox link is not working ...

Comment: Sorry could be because the github repo is private sorry and thank you

Comment: you can add the code "maybe a file where the error has occured" for e.g.  ..

Comment: The CodeSandbox project actually works, having a look at it

Comment: I'm running your code on my local, will let you know